# HTML5 CSS animation effect does not work after reset className on Mac OSX

Tags: javascript, html, css

The CSS animated fadeInLeft effect works on Windows IE but not on Mac OS X when `onClick` fires a second time.

JavaScript the animate effect only work when click button first time for OS X, Windows IE work well

```
image.className=null; //remove class

image.className="animated fadeInLeft"; //add class
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may execute image.className="animated fadeInLeft" Asynchronously. Such as:

```
image.className=null;////remove class

setTimeout( function(){
  image.className="animated fadeInLeft";////add class
},0);
```

Comment: i am so glad to get your help !